# How do I handle an external API callback with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in need of some guidance.  I'm using the 6px.io API to resize images.  The conversion can take a couple of seconds and 6px sends me a post callback when the image has been sent/stored in our S3 bucket.  After the callback, when the image is resized and saved we'd like to download the file to the user's browser from our S3 bucket.

If the resized image is already in our S3 bucket and does not need to be processed by 6px we use send_data to download the file to the user.  Unfortunately I can't use send_data on the callback controller action to initiate download of the file to the user.  How is this done in Rails?

User story:

1. Click medium resize of image menu item of dropdown.
2. Rails controller action builds JSON with post callback url and sends to 6px.
3. 6px returns JSON with input and output information plus the status (complete/fail).
4. File starts to download to user's computer/browser ***This is what I need help with.

Example code (this is for work, can't post the real code):

```
class FakeExampleController < ApplicationController

  def convert_image
    # code ommitted
    @fake_example = FakeExample.find_by(:id)
    image_conversion(params)
  end

  def callback
    # width, height, type variable code ommitted

    if params['status'] == 'complete' 
      converted_file = FakeConvertedImage.create!(filename: @new_file_name, attachment_id:   @fake_example.id, format: type, width: width, height: height)

      send_converted_file( :url => "OUR_S3_BUCKET", :filename => "#{converted_file.filename}", :type => "#{type}", :disposition => 'attachment' )  #This does not work to download file to user's browser.
    else
      raise
        "Image Conversion Failed"
    end
  end

  def image_conversion(params)
    callback_url = fake_example_url.gsub(/localhost:3000/, '********.ngrok.com')

    image_converter = ImageConverter.new(params) #This is a wrapper I made for the 6px-ruby gem
    image_converter
      .convert_type(@fakeexample.mime_type_for_6px(params[:mimetype])
      .resize_images
      .save("OUR_S3_BUCKET_URL", callback_url)
  end

  def send_converted_file(opts={})
    other_opts = opts.select{ |opt,v| /(filename|type|disposition)/ === opt }
    response = { url: opts.fetch(:url), :opts => other_opts }

    send_data( open(URI.encode(response[:url].to_s)).read, response[:opts] )
  end
end
```

I don't get/have any errors.  I just need advice on how to download the file saved in our S3 to the user.

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this if you posted the code you have so far.

Comment: @Jordan I'm not getting any errors so I'm not sure how the code will help.  Also this for work so I can't post real code.  I've posted some similar sample code for reference.

Comment: Well. It seems that you receive the callback outside of the user request/response cycle. To have the browser to download the file after the callback you will need some mechanism for the browser to know when it can get the file. Does that make sense to you? Or I'm completly missing the issue here?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu that makes sense, but I don't know of anything that let's the browser know when it can get the file.  Instead of the callback action/method could I use a sidekiq worker or maybe something like [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests) to ping/check the status of the job in process?  This seems like it should be a common issue when interacting with external APIs.

Comment: Using the callback method seems fine. You just need a way to notify the browser that the file is ready. You will need some javascript for that. You can make it to ping your server to check if the download is ready. Or you can use some pushing strategy. But a polling way should be fine. Like asking in intervals of 5 seconds if the file is ready and redirect the user to the file url when the server says its ready

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu The file is in our S3 bucket not on our server.  If you ping the S3 server and the file is not there a 403: not authorized error is returned.  Not sure if we should be pinging it for download.